# Change The size of the Text box in tkinter without changing the buttons place

Tags: python, tkinter

**Change The size of the Text box in tkinter without changing the buttons place**

Hello, can you please help me my code is the following

```
from tkinter  import *

window = Tk()

# create your first row
l1 = Label(window,text="Title")
l1.grid(row=0,column=0)

e1= Entry(window)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)

l2 = Label(window,text="Author")
l2.grid(row=0,column=2)

e2= Entry(window)
e2.grid(row=0,column=3)


#second row 
l2 = Label(window,text="Year")
l2.grid(row=1,column=0)

e3= Entry(window)
e3.grid(row=1,column=1)

l3 = Label(window,text="ISBN")
l3.grid(row=1,column=2)

e3= Entry(window)
e3.grid(row=1,column=3)

# create your butts diplayther in the 3th column after the 1st row 

b_view = Button(window,text="View ALL", width = 12)
b_view.grid(row=2, column=3)

b_search = Button(window,text="Search Entry", width= 12)
b_search.grid(row=3, column=3)

b_add = Button(window,text = "Add Entry", width=12)
b_add.grid(row=4, column=3)

b_update = Button(window,text="Update Selected", width=12)
b_update.grid(row=5, column=3)

b_delete = Button(window,text = "Delete Selected",width=12)
b_delete.grid(row=6, column = 3)

b_close = Button(window,text= "Close", width =12)
b_close.grid(row=7, column = 3)

#create your output
out = Text(window,height=6 ,width=14)
out.grid(row=4 ,column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

The output is the following:
[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuHqG.png)

Can you please help to display the buttons one below from another ??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "one below from another"? In the image you provided, the buttons are technically one below another. It would be helpful if you also provided an image of the desired structure (a rough image drawn in paint or something).

Comment: Just use: `out.grid(row=2 ,column=0,rowspan=6)`? or `out.grid(row=2 ,column=0,rowspan=6,sticky='news')` and different variations from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting all of the buttons in a frame like this:

```py
buttons_frame = Frame(window)
buttons_frame.grid(row=2, column=3, rowspan=5)

b_view = Button(buttons_frame, text="View ALL", width=12)
b_view.pack()

b_search = Button(buttons_frame, text="Search Entry", width=12)
b_search.pack()

b_add = Button(buttons_frame, text="Add Entry", width=12)
b_add.pack()

b_update = Button(buttons_frame, text="Update Selected", width=12)
b_update.pack()

b_delete = Button(buttons_frame, text="Delete Selected",width=12)
b_delete.pack()

b_close = Button(buttons_frame, text="Close", width=12)
b_close.pack()
```